# What is the maximum zoom level for Mapsforge OSM maps with Android osmdroid & Osmbonuspack?

Tags: android, osmdroid

For my Android geocaching app I use for many years the combination of Mapsforge OSM files with Osmdroid and Osmbonuspack. A superb combination!

The max zoom level is now 18. I don't use the newest versions of Osmdroid and Osmbonuspack.

What is the maximal zoom level? 
Can I increase it with minor effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With osmdroid 5.x, I think you can increase safely up to 20. 
Version 6.0 of osmdroid is on its way and will handle up to zoom level 29.

Comment: Great, thanks, vote+1. When wil the 6.0v approximately be stable, together with osmbonuspack?

Comment: Added the osmdroid 5.6.5 and bonuspack 6.4 to my software, and it works really GREAT!!!  Thank you very much.